# Discrete random variables are defined on a countable probability space. All examples I found are either finite spaces or something like all integers

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables, lebesgue-measure

I wonder if a discrete random variable could be defined on the set {1, 2, 1+1/2, 1-1/2, 2+1/2, 2-1/2, 1+1/3, 1-1/3, 2+1/3, 2-1/3, 1+1/4, ...} i.e on a countable set with 2 accumulation points (or even only 1). In this example there would be no way to order the jump points by magnitude. Kalbfleisch and Prentice are using this ordering implicitly in their book "The statistical analysis of failure time series" when explaining the probability function in chapter 1.2.2 with the 2 bullets at the end. They don't explicitly restrict the discrete case to sets w/o accumulation points

Comment: Definitions are made incredibly generally, for good reason.  Yes, you can have any probability space you want... including the situation you ask about.  Just be warned that you can not have a uniform distribution on a countably infinite space thanks to the $\sigma$-summability requirements in the definition/axioms of probability spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can, and it's pretty simple to do so.

If your support set $A$ is countable, then there exists a bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$. So then all you need to do is construct a random variable $Y$ on the natural numbers, and then your random variable is just $X = f(Y)$.

Comment: That's fully agreed. But I think there is no bijection which maintains the order of N in the A of my example. And that's exactly my problem. In failure time or survival analysis, there are failures or deaths at some time point after start of the observation, and for some analyses these time points must be ordered to see when what percentage of the sample under consideration failed or died. So I conclude in this context accumulation points of A, if any, can only be a single one at the end of the time interval under consideration, to which A converges monotonically